# XML is not well-formed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, xml

I have called an ajax function that gather data from an xml file formatted like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<values>     
  <value date="2015-07-12">37.170</value>
  <value date="2015-07-13">7.190</value>
  <value date="2015-07-12">37.170</value>
  <value date="2015-07-12">3.210</value>
  <value date="2015-07-12">37.20</value>
</values>
```

When I get the response from the console it says 
    not well-formed :1:80

Not sure what this means since when I use xml validator they all tell me that there are no errors. Any help would be awesome to have.

```
        var data = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.xml', // name of file you want to parse
        dataType: "xml", // type of file you are trying to read
        success: parse, // name of the function to call upon success
        async:    false,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert(xhr.responseText);
              console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
                console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                console.log("error: " + err);
        }
    });

    function parse(xml) {
        var items = jQuery(xml).find("values");
        var data = [];
        var values = $(items).text();
        $(document).find("Values").each(function () {
            $(this).find("value").each(function () { data.push($this.text);});
        });
        console.log(data.length);
    }
```

Not sure ethier how to get all of the values into the array.

Comment: What are you doing with the xml that results in this error message?

Comment: I am  wanting to put all of the values into an javascript array to use later on the website. I need to store them in the array so I can do math on them latter and display those calculations.

Comment: can you post your ajax code too please!!

Comment: Posted code in question

Comment: Where is the error occurring? Is your error function firing? Is it one of the console.log lines in there? Is it erroring on the success function? What does the Net tab of your developer tools show you? Have you confirmed that the XML being received by the browser is the XML you think you are sending?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem when I run that code. There are no errors at all here.

Comment: I am not getting a call to the error function. The documents parses but when i try too get the value elements it decides to throw the not well-formed  error.  This is my first time using ajax getting an xml document.  So I do not know how to see the xml document that is being sent. From what I can see when i console.log(xml) it looks like it is being parsed right.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT!

Fiddle is updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/b62tx8Ln/1/

No need to parse data with parseXML.

Erik Phillips is probably right about the double parsing. Anyways, this should work.

Note the use of ECHO in fiddle..... just to simulate a local xml-file.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'test.xml', // name of file you want to parse
        dataType: "xml", // type of file you are trying to read
        success: parse, // name of the function to call upon success
        async:    false,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
            alert("error");
        }
    });

    function parse(xmldata) {
        $(xmldata).find("value").each(function(){
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    }
```

Comment: With this function do you have to use a string xml because my xml is dynamically generated every hour?

Comment: No, the `xml` string would be equal to to the response text/xml of the ajax call.

Comment: when using a file name would it be any different than calling a normal file in a function  $.parseXML(test.xml). When i call it like this nothing happens

Comment: I have edited the fiddle. Hope it solves something for you

Comment: This is probably a stupid question but would it be possible to put it in a js function like function getxml(id){//code here}

Comment: Is it possible that I can get the First and current date values in the same loop?

Comment: have been on vacation, not sure if still relevant. You can address the elements directly, see this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b62tx8Ln/2/ where I use the first() method

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to parse it twice, per the documentation:

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

Thus I'm imagining that this is what you are looking for:

```
function parse(xml) {
  //var items = jQuery(xml).find("values");
  var items = xml.find("values");
  var data = [];
  var values = $(items).text();
  $(document).find("Values").each(function () {
    $(this).find("value").each(function () { data.push($this.text);});
  });
  console.log(data.length);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the not well formed error any more but I am getting this error TypeError: xml.find is not a function test.html:28:23. I looked where it was and do not understand how the function find works before but now it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else having a problem parsing non-well-formed (self-closing tags) xml in IE, `$(xmlthing).find('nodename').each...` works, whereas IE will parse `$(xmlthing).children('nodename').each...` (which is fine in FF and Chrome), as nested.

That is:

`<thing />
 <thing />
 <thing />`

will be 3 things in FF/Chrome, but one in IE if you use $(node).children(thing)

$(node).find(thing) will give you 3 things in all browsers. Thanks @Steen